# After mounting a Windows SMB share, how can I determine the windows "creator" of a file?

Tags: macos, network, windows, sharing, smb

I've mounted a Windows SMB share to my Mac. On a windows machine you can open the "File Properties" dialog for folders in this network share and see different "Owners" for whoever created the file:

[image]

But on my Mac I'm not able to see this ownership information:

[image]

I've also tried mounting the share from the command line which works fine:

```
mkdir /Volumes/ShareName
mount -t smbfs //user@server/ShareName /Volumes/ShareName
```

But I'm not able to see any additional information via the Terminal when I look at the files in `/Volumes/ShareName`

```
> ll
drwx------  1 cwd  staff    16K Jan 22 14:04 .
drwx------  1 cwd  staff    16K Jan 25 11:16 ..
-rwx------@ 1 cwd  staff    11K Jan 22 14:05 Thumbs.db
-rwx------  1 cwd  staff    29B Jan 22 13:36 test.txt
-rwx------  1 cwd  staff     0B Jan 22 13:36 test2.txt

> xattr Thumbs.db
encryptable
```

`xattr` also doesn't show me anything useful in the extended attributes.

How can I find the "Owner" property on a windows SMB shared file?

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted.  Sure, it's a network-related question.  Sure, it's windows-related, too, but it's from the perspective of a mac user.  I was brought here by the internets because I had the same question, and the accepted answer also answered my question, so... +1 from me. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't get the ownership properties of files on SMB/Samba shares on anything other than Windows. Mac OS / Linux implementations of Samba don't parse that info when reading the share, most probably because of the differences in how the extended attributes are stored between the OS's, and that the Share properties are determined by the hosting system and are locked down to prevent network users from altering the properties of the Share.